# Docker Removing Laravel Storage Image on Rebuilding

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I just implemented docker container for my Laravel Application.
But what I don't understand is, the container doesn't mirror the latest build of my image.

I tried to restart the container, It's still using the old codes.
I also tried to just build the images and use `docker compose down && docker compose up -d` but the code is not changing.

What's working for me is remove completely container using `docker compose down --volume` and up again using `docker compose up -d`.
with flag `--volume` on it.
But i lost my storage images.
How to correctly updating my codes?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-fpm:
    image: laravel_image:1.0.0
    volumes:
      - shared-data:/var/www/html:consistent
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=local
      - ...
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:443"
    volumes:
      - shared-data:/var/www/html:consistent
      - ...
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
  
volumes:
  shared-data:
```

Dockerfile

```
# Install PHP FPM
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# apt-get update
RUN apt-get update

# One Line
RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev libzip-dev libpng-dev software-properties-common

# Install PDO and PDO_SQL for PostgreSQL
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql


# Libraries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev && docker-php-ext-install zip

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# COPY
COPY . /var/www/html
RUN cp ./.env.example ./.env

# Set permissions for the /storage directory (adjust permissions as needed)
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

# Install Composer globally
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install application dependencies using Composer
COPY ./composer.json ./composer.lock /var/www/html/

# Create a non-root user and switch to it
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' myuser
USER myuser

# Install
RUN composer install --no-interaction

# Switch back to root user if needed
USER root

# Start PHP FPM
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

**EDITED DOCKER COMPOSE FILE**

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend_php:
    image: backend_php:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=local
      - ...
    expose:
      - 9000
    networks:
      - backend_network

  backend_nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: backend_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
    ports:
      - "8080:443"
    depends_on:
      - backend_php
    networks:
      - backend_network

networks:
  backend_network:
```

Comment: is the project in `shared_data`? If `docker-compose.yml` is in the same level as `shared-data` change the `- shared-data` to `- ./shared-data`

Comment: you might need to rebuild the docker images.

Comment: shared_data is my way to share data between containers. This case is php-fpm and nginx. That's a volume, not a directory.

I tried to use `docker compose up -d --build` but still the same, the code inside container is not reflected to code in my local machine.

Comment: Can you change the docker-compose? Instead of `shared-data` change the value to folder name where your laravel app is. (if your app is in the same level as the docker-compose, use `./app-folder`, else do `../` or `/somewhere/` if needed. Remove `:consistent` then update the volume name. docker compose down -v then rebuild (delete container and image)

Comment: Also.. Check your dockerfile. Remove the `COPY . /var/www/html`.

Comment: This will copy the project to your container per build (or at least per `up`)

Comment: I got your point. I think that's my problem too. `COPY` the app per `up`. But as you can see in the Dockerfile, I installed everything in Dockerfile, like `composer install` and set permissions. How do I manage to install the application in the container if the app is not exists in the container? I try to avoid `build` application in my local machine if that's possible. In my Dockerfile, `COPY` is what make the code exists in the container and then I can build it. @Mr.Kenneth

Comment: That is what the `volume` is for. Instead of copy, it mounts your project to the docker container. Like what symlink does.

Comment: tldr, remove the `copy` then update the docker-compose

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work. Error on building, file's not exists.
I think the COPY is necessary due to `copy` the code into the container. Otherwise, the container will not have the codes.

Comment: Then the docker-compose or dockerfile itself has issues. I will try to check again.

Comment: btw is this project in early stages? If you still have issues with docker, I suggest you try Laravel Sail: `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` more on https://laravel.com/docs/10.x#getting-started-on-windows

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying. Sorry for my late response. The thing is I'm trying to build the app(s) with docker. So it's not only the Laravel that experience this, also my other app such as React. The code in container is just not reflected with the local machine code. Deep diving this problem for now. I will let you know if I find something also. I think somethings to do with this volumes.

Comment: No problem. I am 80% sure that the problem is in the docker-compose + volumes. Last advice, run `docker system prune -a` (will delete all docker container, image, volumes, etc) then rebuild. **This will also delete other docker items for other projects** Though you can rebuild them too. Use flag `-af` if you want to execute without confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the container, you mount a Docker named volume `shared_data` over the `/var/www/html` directory.  If there's anything in this volume, its contents replace that directory in the image – that is, all of your code is hidden by the contents of the named volume.

*The first time only that you run this*, if the volume hasn't been initialized, Docker copies content from the image into the volume.  This only happens the very first time you run the container (which is why deleting the volume helps), and it doesn't work for bind mounts, Kubernetes persistent volumes, or any other kind of storage.  I'd avoid using this mechanism.

For the PHP application, I'd only mount volumes for the actual storage, and avoid mounting volumes over the code.

```yaml
services:
  php-fpm:
    volumes:
      - storage:/var/www/html/storage
      - cache:/var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
```

For the Nginx proxy, build a custom image that `COPY` the static assets.  Don't try to share contents using a volume.

```sh
# Dockerfile.nginx
FROM nginx
COPY ./ /usr/share/nginx/html/
# don't need EXPOSE, ENTRYPOINT, CMD, &c.
```

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    # no volumes:
```

Now `docker-compose up --build` will rebuild and restart *both* containers, but you're getting the code and static assets directly out of the respective images, so you're not hiding them with old content from the volume.

Comment: Hi David @David Maze. First of all, thank you for your reply. It actually make sense now why my code always replaced. I actually did fix the docker. But what I did is kind of different than my old approach (and you, since you were replying my old approach). So what I did is something that "link" my container directories into my local host directories. I got rid of the `shared-data` and just define the link directories (like my edited post).

Comment: So in docker file, i only COPY the files and run the build with `bash` inside the container (dokcer exec -it ...). The result is now the code is reflected to my local host code. But is it good approach?

Comment: My general experience has been that, if you're trying to run code that only exists on the host and you aren't using Docker's image system at all, it's easier to use host tools and skip Docker.