# How can I resolve permission errors between a built php-fpm dockerfile and a nginx contain so there files are served

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Laravel project which I would like to deploy to our internal network using docker.  I've written the below Dockerfile to build an image from php-fpm:8.2 which installs the requirements, then copies in the src files.

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# This help script for find the require modules for PHP Extension
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

# Run the helper script and ask it to install the required extensions
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions pdo_mysql openssl mbstring tokenizer xml zip gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy the rest of the application code to the web directory
COPY . /var/www/html

# Install all the composer dependencies
RUN composer update

RUN composer install

# Expose port 9000 for PHP-FPM
EXPOSE 9000
```

I then have a docker compose file to spin up the built image a long with mysql and nginx.  I have a shared volume so the build container and nginx can access the same files.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app_db
      MYSQL_USER: app_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: app_pass

  php_web:
    container_name: my-php-container
    build: 
      context: ./laravel
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    volumes:
      - app:/var/www/html 

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - app:/var/www/html 
    depends_on:
      - php_web
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:

volumes:
  app: {}
```

When I terminal into the two containers I can see they have the same files for the /var/html/www directory as expected.

When I try to access the website I'm getting 403 permission errors.  When I check the permissions on the files from the terminal with in the containers they are all set to root.

How do I ensure the files have the correct permission so they are served by nginx as expected?  I'm new to docker, so I'm not sure if I'm doing any of this correctly and I would like to deploy a few other applications in the future via docker to make my life easier, any assistance is welcome.

I've tried adding a run command to Dockerfile to create a user and group for nginx and chmod all the files once they have been copied, however after I started the container the files still belonged to root when I terminaled into it

Comment: I describe a setup in [Docker Removing Laravel Storage Image on Rebuilding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77101858/docker-removing-laravel-storage-image-on-rebuilding) that avoids this shared volume.  The permission problems you highlight here are one problem with it; that question notes that the shared volume never is updated and so changes to your application get lost.  Does the approach I describe in that question of building a dedicated Nginx image help you here?